# How to convert HTTPPostedFileBase to Google Drive API File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, google-drive-api

What I'm trying to do is very simple, but I can't find an answer for it.

I have an HTTPPostedFileBase, newfile, that I want to convert into a Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File so that I can upload it to Google Drive. But I can't find a way to convert the HTTPPostedFileBase into the Google Drive file. I'm using an HTTPPostedFileBase because this is an Asp.Net site where the user can upload a file that will go into Google drive. Here's the code I have:

```cs
//newfile: HTTPPostedFileBase
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File deliverable = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File(newfile); //This line gives an error, no matching constructor
deliverable.Parents.Add(folderID);
FilesResource.CreateRequest request = service.Files.Create(deliverable);
request.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it, but it ended up not involving converting file types. Instead, the request was made a different type and used a different constructor, with the "deliverable" variable providing metadata and the file itself provided by the HTTPPostedFileBase's input stream.

```cs
//newfile: HTTPPostedFileBase
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File deliverable = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
deliverable.Parents = new List<string>();
deliverable.Name = newfile.FileName;
deliverable.Parents.Add(folderID);
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(deliverable, newfile.InputStream, newfile.ContentType);
request.Upload();
```